# No longer earning rep for editing posts

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

In the last week+ I've edited a lot of posts (through seeing many issues) and earned reasonable rep for it (despite accepted edits in the suggested queue). But, for some reason, I no-longer earn rep for editing... I noticed this in the last 24 hours and I'd like to know **why**?

I've had both the time and inclination to edit posts - Because I feel I'm contributing, earning rep and also because I believe it's valuable to others (if a post is clearer, even by a marginal amount, then people are more likely to readily understand, comment and answer!).

My edits have included many corrections including, but not limited to:

- Correcting or enabling code display (through poor markdown)
- Improving formatting
- Grammar and associated issues
- Plural usage and punctuation
- Etc.

And in various combinations.

... But never removing or correcting the manner in which the OP communicates. Sometimes, I find myself wanting to just apply the `<code>` tag to missed opportunities, but I can't (yet).

Sure, there are probably instances of edits where I've done little to improve a post; but sometimes a *'little'* counts, but I'm confused as to why I'm no-longer receiving rep for my efforts...

Is there some sort of imposed/modded limit/flag for users editing too many posts or with too many rejected edits?

Comment: There's a 1k limit to edits.

Comment: @Mysticial I've made 501 to date!

Comment: There you have it, 500 x 2 = 1000 reputation. Plus, one more upvote, and you're above 2k, which means you can no longer *suggest* edits anyway but will instead be actually *making* edits.

Comment: Now fully understood.

Comment: So do we get any reputation for making edits after 2k reputation.?

Comment: No. After 2k it doesn't count for new rep.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Stack Overflow reputation is 1913, which is close to the 2000 cutoff to gain full editing permissions. When you go over that mark, then you can no longer *suggest* edits but actually get to *make* edits.

As Mysticial says, the limit on suggested edits is 1000 reputation, or 500 **accepted** suggested edits, so you effectively exhausted your suggested edits just in time for it to not make an impact on your reputation anymore. Perfect timing! ;)

Comment: Oh the irony... But at no time did the system intelligently tell me "You've reached your limit"...

Comment: @nickhar If your suggestions are good (and they can't be too bad if you reach the cap), the system doesn't want you to stop :D

Comment: @DanielFischer Meh, I've read and pointed to the FAQ more times than I'd like to mention, but still... I missed it.

Comment: I feel a feature-request coming on...

Answer (score 7):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through
>   suggested edits

You've currently made [597 suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714488/nickhar?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) - assuming at least 500 were accepted, that makes the 1000 rep limit earned off them.

Comment: Appreciate your comment here - missed that oh-so-important point in the FAQ.