# Notification of imposed/notional profile limits

Tags: feature-request, notifications, rate-limiting

In the last 24 hours, I hit the +1000 rep limit for suggested edits on SO.

Despite my new-found knowledge of SO and how one should participate, I had neglected to understand (as a fairly new user), that the rep for my edits would effectively max-out at +1k rep.

Given that this limit (and a few others) exist, surely it would be productive/pro-active to notify users that a limit has been hit!? by Either:

- On-screen notification
- Profile note
- Email

Nothing more than a suggestion, but it would have [saved time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155112/no-longer-earning-rep-for-editing-posts) for many parties on Meta (including myself).

Comment: Ah, I can't do math today. Earlier I think I mentioned that you only needed 1 more upvote. You need about 9 more to hit 2k ;)

Comment: That's not my point here. I'm more in search of UX for SO users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases, this might be helpful; however, in this case, we don't want you to stop editing, especially if you're doing a good job of it. If you're doing it just for the points, you're probably doing it for the wrong reason.

With that said, the notification is in your profile. It didn't take you long to notice that you hit the cap. ;)

Comment: Oh you're such a stickler. NO I'm not doing it solely for the rep, but like many others, effort should be rewarded. Mea culpa.